# Linux terminal interface/Software for Wiktionary

Tags: linux, dictionary, command-line, wiktionary

Basically, I want approximately the same output as below for german words.
I haven't found any databases fitting to use with the "dict" protocol/program.

Therefore, I thought I'd have the best chances with wiktionary, as its public domain, but I haven't found an interface/terminal program for it (just for Wikipedia, which is additionally not colored)

Do you have any ideas?

[image: output of 'dict -d gcide "ambivalence" | colorit']

Comment: You can try with this script https://tonybaldwin.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/search-wiktionary-from-the-bash-cli/